# Google Drive API - Searching for files within folders

Tags: google-drive-api

This question is not how about to search within folders, but why I'm not getting the correct results.

This is how I'm formatting my search request which is basically a search for "mount" inside two folders.

```
GET: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=fullText contains 'mount' AND ('{folder_id}' in parents OR '{folder_id}' in parents)
Headers:
  Authorization: Bearer {access_token}
```

Which gets me this response:

```json
{
  "kind": "drive#fileList",
  "incompleteSearch": false,
  "files": []
}
```

When I make the request with code, I don't get any results nor when I use an API client to manually send the request. But, whenever I use the "Try it now" in the [Google Drive files list API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) I do get results... which is perplexing to me since I'm using the exact same query there (copy/pasting). Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using these permissions

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata

Things I've tried:

- Encoded the full query, with and without encoding the single quotation marks.
- Copying the full encoded query from the "Try it now" tool.
- Reduced the number of folders to search through down to one (it works in this case, anything more than one results zero results).
- Changed the position of the search and the folder query.
- Lowercased "AND" and "OR" inside the query.

Comment: In order to correctly understand your situation, can I ask you about your situation? 1. The account of `{access_token}` of `Authorization: Bearer {access_token}` is the same as the account you tested `But, whenever I use the "Try it now" in the Google Drive files list API I do get results`? 2. When you tested "Try it now", you used other parameters except for `q`? 3. And, as a test case, when you use only the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` and retrieve the access token again and test your request, what result will you obtain?

Comment: 4. And also, when you test the following curl command by replacing `###` with your access token and placing `folderId1` and `folderId2` with your folder IDs, what result will you obtain? `curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ###" "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=fullText%20contains%20%27mount%27%20AND%20(%27folderId1%27%20in%20parents%20OR%20%27folderId2%27%20in%20parents)"`

Comment: Sure thing. 1. Yes, it's the same account. When I reduce the folder parent search to only one folder, it pulls the results (correctly) from the same account but stops working as soon as I try to search through more than one folder. 2. I did not touch any other parameters other than "q" and the permissions to match the same ones I use. 3. Using ONLY the .../auth/drive permission I'm still unable to get results.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. From your reply, I understood the answers to Q1 to Q3. In this case, I would like to confirm the answer to Q4.

Comment: 4. I've already tried to encode the single quotes but I don't get any results. But I did try your query with corrected details, but still did not get any results.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I cannot understand `I've already tried to encode the single quotes but I don't get any results.`. About `But I did try your query with corrected details, but still did not get any results.`, unfortunately, when I tested my proposed curl command, I can confirm the same result with "Try it now". I apologize for this. So, in this case, it is required to know the detailed flow for correctly replicating your situation. So, can I ask you about the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current situation? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you clarify what you mean by detailed flow?

Comment: Thank you for replying. First, I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. From your reply, in the current stage, I think that correctly replicating your situation will lead to the reason for your current issue. Because when I tested my proposed curl command, the same result with "Try it now" is obtained. So, about `Can you clarify what you mean by detailed flow?`, I thought that I'm required to know the detailed method (flow) for correctly replicating your situation. If you cannot understand my English. I apologize again.

Comment: I think that the reason when I tested my proposed curl command, the same result with "Try it now" is obtained, and I cannot replicate your situation is due to my poor skill. About this situation, I think that I have to apologize for my poor skill, and I have to study more.

Comment: I figured it out! I went through your questions again very carefully and I realized that I'm using a Google Service Account and not the main account (I had forgotten about it, sorry). So, technically, it was not the same account even though the Google Service Account had access to some folders of the main account, but not all of the folders. I solved this by adding the Google Service Account to all of the folders I need to search through. If you post an answer stating this, I'll accept it as the answer. Thank you for your help, kind person!

Comment: Thank you for replying and confirming it, again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. In order to understand the process for achieving the reason for the issue, I posted my comments and your result as an answer. When this discussion is useful, I'm glad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to correctly understand your situation, I asked the following 4 questions.

1. The account of `{access_token}` of `Authorization: Bearer {access_token}` is the same as the account you tested `But, whenever I use the "Try it now" in the Google Drive files list API I do get results`?
2. When you tested "Try it now", you used other parameters except for `q`?
3. As a test case, when you use only the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` and retrieve the access token again and test your request, what result will you obtain?
4. When you test the following curl command by replacing `###` with your access token and placing `folderId1` and `folderId2` with your folder IDs, what result will you obtain?

   - `curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ###" "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=fullText%20contains%20%27mount%27%20AND%20(%27folderId1%27%20in%20parents%20OR%20%27folderId2%27%20in%20parents)"`

As the result, from the section 1, it was found as follows.

> I went through your questions again very carefully and I realized that I'm using a Google Service Account and not the main account. So, technically, it was not the same account even though the Google Service Account had access to some folders of the main account, but not all of folders.